# Custom jQuery steps; how do I make them clickable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-steps

I'm trying to use an example.

It is all well and nice, but I need to make those steps on top clickable. I tried:

```
var clickedIndex;
$('#progressbar').click(function(){
    clickedIndex = $(this).attr(id);
});
current_fs=index(clickedIndex);
```

and updated some other related places, but it didn't get me anywhere enough.

[Here](http://codepen.io/atakan/pen/gqbIz) is a working example.

Comment: Need a  much better explanation of what expectations are. There is only one `#progressbar`

Comment: For example, when I'm on the third step, I should be able to click step 1 and see step 1 without pressing previous button till I get where I want to be.

Comment: There are a variety of step wizard plugins you can use... suggest trying those

Comment: Give each li a class and then you can use those as your selectors.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#progressbar li').on('click', function(){
  var step = $(this).index() - 1;
  $('fieldset').eq(step).find('.next').trigger('click');
});
```

It triggers a click on the `next` button of the step that was clicked

Comment: Couldn't understand how is that supposed to work. Ok, maybe if I put that in a while{}, let me try something. Thanks.